# Anime/Cartoon with a Giant Police(?) Robot

Tags: story-identification, anime, robots

I remember watching this show around 20 years ago, likely on a children's cartoon channel (probably Cartoon Network, Toonami or Fox Kids) so it could well be a 90s cartoon or a re-run. Don't remember much of the story other than they would break out this giant robot to fight crime or whatever the disaster of the day was. I remember the robot itself being pretty bland compared to other anime styles but still quite cool and sleek and could fly using rockets in its feet. It was all black from what I can remember and looked very much like someone from a SWAT team or the police (possibly with a visor). Haven't been able to place the show whatsoever and it's really nagging at me...

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Please check out the [guidelines for a story-id question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) and [for an anime-id question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) to see if there are any other details they can help you recall.

Comment: Was the robot formed of smaller robots combined together?

Comment: It was a single giant robot. No smaller parts. It might not have had people in it at all actually. Might have been remote controlled

Comment: Megas XLR immediately comes to mind. Also, The Big O was on Toonami and had a black mecha.

Comment: I remember Megas XLR well! :) But not it sadly, this one wasn't as "out there". It was  more toned down for sure. Japanese style as opposed to American style robot cartoons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Gigantor the space age robot? I know it had a sequel to the old sixties series. It was used as a 'guardian of the peace' and had rockets to fly with
>
> https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigantor

[image]

YouTube link to the sequel series,  possibly what you viewed, he can be seen flying about five seconds into the intro

Comment: YES!!!! That's the one! ...it seems so cheesy looking at it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps its the Patlabor series?

It fits the data of being a robot/mecha to fight crime or disasters.

It does not fit in the fact this carry a people inside (but can be remote controlled) and as far as I remember it cant fly.

Comment: @DannyMcG, it may be, but GroomedGorrila, does not mention if the animation is that old.

Comment: The other aspect of *Patlabor* that stuck with me were the huge revolver cartridges being ejected after shooting.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots   Do you image the weight of the full rounds?